# Using a bound variable to refer to a GRAPH in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, arq

I have used bound variables of Uri from triple patterns as GRAPH arguments before but when I use the result of the BIND/URI/CONCAT shown below it is not behaving as expected: it is not matching any known graph. I have checked the ?graph variable is resolving to the expected Graph Uri. If the pattern should work is there a variable scoping issue I am overlooking or something?

```
       SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE
       { 
        GRAPH <http://www.interition.net/g1>
          { 
            <s1> :aProperty ?literal .

            BIND ( URI(CONCAT("http://www.interition.net/graphs/", ?literal )) AS ?graph) .
          }

          GRAPH ?graph { 
                  ?s ?p ?o .
              }
    }
```

Example nQuads

```
<s1> <http://www.interition.net/ref/aProperty> "g2" <http://www.interition.net/g1> .
<s2> <http://www.interition.net/ref/aState> "happy"   <http://www.interition.net/graphs/g2> .
```

Comment: Do you get bound values for ?graph at all?  E.g., if you remove the `graph graph { ?s ?p ?o }` and just select ?literal and ?graph, what do you get?

Comment: Yes, if I have a SELECT * in the projection and remove the second GRAPH declaration, and its block, I get the ?literal and ?graph values with the latter as a URI. If I take a URI value and provide as an argument to GRAPH with a spo block it works.

Comment: Can you show some nquads data so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Edited the question. I am fabricating the query and data obviously. I am looking to know if I should expect it to work.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor hi, can I help with any more information ? If I should expect it to work then I'll spend more time investigating it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue roots in the triplestore we are using. I fabricated two dummy ttl files which I uploaded into two graphs in Jena's Fuseki and the query worked just like Andy demonstrated it.

However, we are currently using an older version of [BigData](http://bigdata.com/) as our store at Interition, which doesn't seem to support this type of variable passing to graphs... I will try it on the latest release and we will reconsider whether to upgrade or switch over to Fuseki. If the issue persists in the latest release too, I will raise it with the developer team.

Comment: Slight correction - BigData has worked with the variable passing of  graph uri but appears not to when you construct the variable from a literal using the BIND(uri(concat(...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `<s1>` in the data does not match `<s1>` in the query.

Try printing the query with "arq.qparse" (or just printing the "toString" in a program).  The relative URI for `<s1>` is resolved.

How did the N-Quads get get created?  The API does not check URIs.

Try:

```
PREFIX  ref:  <http://www.interition.net/ref/>

SELECT  ?graph ?s ?p ?o
WHERE
  { GRAPH <http://www.interition.net/g1>
      { ?s1 ref:aProperty ?literal
        BIND(uri(concat("http://www.interition.net/graphs/", ?literal)) AS ?graph)
      }
    GRAPH ?graph
      { ?s ?p ?o }
  }
```

I get:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| graph                                 | s    | p          | o       |
=======================================================================
| <http://www.interition.net/graphs/g2> | <s2> | ref:aState | "happy" |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I did fabricate by hand because I can't show the real query or the data.  I didn't create a real data set and test as I was just looking to find out if it should work in principle.  I will reproduce more thoroughly and post back.

Comment: As you seem to have noticed, <aProperty> is also a problem.

Comment: Yes, as I said it was fabricated so this code and data has never been run. I was asking in principle.  I have someone making some dummy data to post back to conclude the question.

Comment: The two GRAPH blocks are joined together - logically the two GRAPH pars are evaluated then a join of the results of each is done.  There happens to be a faster way which ARQ will find (a form of index join). The answer to the original question is "yes, you can do that"

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably related to how query evaluation is implemented in your RDF store. When the first `GRAPH` block is evaluated it results in a set of bindings for `?graph`. Typically, this binding will only be applied across the two groups at the very last stage of the query evaluation, where the blocks will be joined across this variable. It is not required that that it is used in actually matching the second graph pattern. An alternative way of writing the query would be to match the graphs in a filter:

```
PREFIX  ref:  <http://www.interition.net/ref/>

SELECT  ?graph ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {
   GRAPH <http://www.interition.net/g1> {
      ?s1 ref:aProperty ?literal
      BIND(uri(concat("http://www.interition.net/graphs/", ?literal)) AS ?graph1)
   }
   GRAPH ?graph2 {
      ?s ?p ?o
   }
   FILTER(?graph1 = ?graph2)
}
```